# How to center a text vertically?

Tags: html, css

Lets imagine this:

```
<span>IMAGE</span><span>Title `this text must be centered vertically`</span>
<div>
 content 
 content 
 content
</div>
```

how to center the text in the 2nd span?

Comment: [This page](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html), which I found using [this Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=center+text+vertically+in+span) (it is the first match) should answer your question comprehensively.

Comment: What have you tried? Aligning items vertically is not straight-forward but has been answered many times before; have you done a search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not help...

```
  <div>
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: -60px;">Center this in content</div>
```

You can go [here](http://jsbin.com/apelel/2/) to view and change it.

Comment: I figured it out, thx It must be put in <p> and must has line-height: 100%; Im sometimes confused about DIV, SPAN, P .....